# Boost PTree used just for reading file or for storing the values too?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a configuration file, that is a json. I have created a class (ConfigFile) that reads that file and store the values (using boost parser and ptree). I am wandering is it a good practice to use the ptree as a member of the ConfigFile class, or I shall use it just for reading the json and store the values in a map member?

Comment: it's a matter of taste and judgement

Comment: Can you be more explicit, like give some examples, please?

Comment: Do you have time for that? If not, why would I?

Comment: The idea is that I thought to use the ptree as a private member of the class and in the getValForField() function I do the ptree::get and verification that the value is correct (like not empty for string, or positive of between bounds for int), but I got a colleague suggestion to use a map and use the ptree just for reading and do all the verifications in the constructor. What would you suggest and why? :)

Comment: Ask your colleague? A good reason could be: less code changes if implementation changes. Another classic reason: keep property tree out of the header. The latter can also be fixed with the pimpl idiom

Comment: Well he left a while ago (from the enterprise), so what do you suggest? Do you have an opinion, or 2 ? :)

Comment: I already gave you mine. It's worth more to decide for the right reasons than because someone gave you blank advice

Comment: Ok, my opinion is to have the map, like this I am throwing the exceptions at reading time, if any miss-format

Comment: Sounds like a good reason. Everything has flipsides (Eg likely you just hard coded the mapped values to std::string). It would be hard/impossible for an outsider to with these factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say what matters is the `ConfigFile`'s interface. If you can keep it consistent with either version, it shouldn't be a problem to just choose one and switch to the other if you feel the need without breaking anything.

> Keep property tree out of the header. The latter can also be fixed with the pimpl idiom.

**@sehe**'s comment makes a lot of sense here as well and is something to remember.

Comment: so that's also why not saving all in the ptree and just do reads in the "getters"... :)